# An acceptable way to express the maximum of a union of two finite sets

Tags: notation

Suppose that $A= \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ and $B= \{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ are two sets of real numbers.

In such a situation, I usually find myself writing $\max\{a_i, b_i\mid i=1, \ldots, n\}$ as shorthand for the maximum of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n, b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$.

I'm not sure I have seen this exact notation elsewhere. In general, is it an unambiguous way to express the maximum of the union of two finite sets of reals (with equal cardinality)?

Comment: $\sup (A\cup B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is a little ambiguous, I suppose you intend to write $$\max \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{a_i,b_i\}\right).$$

I would prefer to write $\max(A \cup B)$ instead.

Comment: Yes, my notation is supposed to denote the same thing as $\max\big (\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{a_i, b_i\}\big )$. It seems as though you were able to infer the correct meaning of my notation. So do you find it ambiguous or just not ideal?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 What you wrote is not traditional or formally correct but yes the meaning is clear. I prefer this answer's last suggestion, because I don't like reading indices when there's an alternative.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 My hunch would be to interpret the way you mean, but one could also take $a_i,b_i$ to mean $(a_i, b_i)$, especially with a programming background it is quite common.

Comment: @gt6989b That was my main concern. That's why I usually write something like "the integer $\max\{a_i, b_i \mid i =1, \ldots, n\}$."

Comment: @EthanBolker Out of curiosity, what do you mean it is not "formally correct"?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Your definition is not formally correct because in set builder notation there can be just one variable before the bar, with a proposition about that variable after. And your not quite right notation fails if $A$ and $B$ don't have the same number of elements. Pairing them up just to take the union is a bad idea.

Comment: @EthanBolker Your point about set-builder notation makes sense. But I am only talking about the situation where $|A| = |B|$.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Your readers will be able to figure out what you mean. All I am saying is that this answer provides what I think is a better way to say it.